# Get values from all checkboxes with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have N-* number checkbox, on every page, it is always different. I use the plugin js: iCheck.

The problem at the level checked in the checkbox to send via js its value. if marked 5, 8 and 9, the value must be:

5 8 9

I also get to get the value of only one, the last marked checkbox, even if marked at least 10 pieces.

My JS code:

```
   $('.iCheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var checkedValue = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(checkedValue);
    var itemsbought = document.getElementById(checkedValue).innerHTML;
    $('.gds-buy-items-bought').html('<div class="item">'+itemsbought+'</div>');
    });
```

Code:

> $('.gds-buy-items-bought').html(''+itemsbought+'');

Works only 1 time 1 value. And i need to load all values and as many times as I have mentioned checkbox is ..

I suffer a half hours already and tried to shove cycles until no chance.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of example HTML that you're working with, to show the structure?

Comment: what dou you mean by `N-*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use array instead of single variable because value is updated on single variable on every check not appended

```
var itemsbought=[];
 $('.iCheck').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var checkedValue = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(checkedValue);
    var v=document.getElementById(checkedValue).innerHTML;
     itemsbought.push( v);
    $('.gds-buy-items-bought').html('<div class="item">'+itemsbought+'</div>');
    });
```

You should also look up here , what i am suggesting is

```
var v=document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')).innerHTML;
```

or very simple as suggested

```
 var v=$(this).html();
```

Comment: What on earth are you doing `document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'))` for? You already have the node you want to find – in that line – in the `this`.